# Posting objective c form to rails api json response

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails, json

Im trying to post to my rails api, but when i post to rails the username parameter is username=<UITextField. Rails is using json.

When i use curl it works perfectly

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"test","password":"test"}' http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/v1/users/signin
```

Objective C

```
-(IBAction)Login:(id)sender{

    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    self.receivedData = data;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/v1/users/signin"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url standardizedURL]];

    //set http method
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    //initialize a post data
    NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@", username, password];

    //set request content type we MUST set this value.
    [request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //initialize a connection from request
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];


}
```

Rails API

```
def authenticate

        user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])

        respond_to do |format|
          if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
            format.json { render json: "Signed In"}
          else
            format.json { render json: "Wrong username or password"}
          end
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like username and password are textfields thus you cannot submit the object. For this to work you have to submit the text within the object

```
NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@", username.text, password.text];
```